# setvisibilty(View.GONE) on image view is not working

Tags: android, android-imageview

[imageview is still taking space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igLWm.png)

```
        ImageView img =(ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);


if(currentword.hasImg()){
    img.setImageResource(currentword.getImgId());
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

setvisibility of image view is GONE but still image view is taking space.
please do help.
anyone!!
android
android-layout
[xml code part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QVif.png)
[xml code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz1IN.png)

Comment: please share your xml code.

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: i have added screenshots of xml code

Answer (score 3):

I think your *ImageView* is inside parent view that takes space, you should apply `setVisibility(View.GONE);` for parent view.

Comment: It's probably the reason, yes. But we can't be sure as long as OP hasn't shared his xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

Initially the ImageView set visible is "Gone" in XML file,

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `ImageView` height and width to be **`wrap_content`**
It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the layout height and layout width of image view all things will be handled